# What makes you keep on reading articles in your non-English native language, while the same information might be published in English?

Tags: publications, language, reading

As a future French PhD student (in Computer-Supported Collaborative Learning) that legally HAS TO write his thesis in French, I am a bit concerned about the fact that less people would be able to read it and it got me thinking: why do you keep reading articles in your native language, when some ideas you find might also be published in English?

1. To those who are not English native speakers, do you read articles in your native language?
2. If so, what is it that you find in these articles compared to English-written ones? Are you just looking for useful information for your own research or are you motivated by something else?
3. How would you cite these articles in your own English-written paper?

I understand that using one's own native language can be justified for some fields such as social sciences, but here I am asking about "exact" and computer sciences.

Comment: I strongly recommend publishing an English version of any scientific non-English manuscript you publish. Unless, of course, it is important to you that people *not* read it.

Comment: @Bitwise I am not asking about whether I should publish in English or not, as I will do everything I can to write in English. The French law explicitely tells that the PhD thesis has to be written in French, which is kind of stupid but I don't have any power on that. On the contrary, I want to know what incentives make people read articles in their native languages.

Comment: I understood that. I just thought it is important to stress (for anyone reading this question) that you should make an extra effort to publish an English version.

Comment: @Bitwise Agreed. I am already prepared to do mostly everything in English, except for the thesis that will also be in French.

Comment: It's equally valid to ask why native-English speakers would read non-English papers. I often read papers in French (in fluid dynamics/turbulence/combustion) simply because *there are papers written in French*. So I read whatever language I need to in order to get the information and references I need.

Comment: From your comments to the posts, I would suggest modifying your question to include more about what kind of answers do you want. For example, it seems you want to know if there is ever valuable information in non-English papers about the hard sciences. This would stop many of the 'yes I do it and there is no problem' kind of answers you are getting.

Comment: @earthling Done, I hope it makes it clearer now.

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ that the thesis has to be in French? I am currently a PhD student in France, do not speak French and can not hope to improve it enough to write a thesis in it. My supervisors assure me that I can do my thesis in English. Also, I know at least a handful of people who got their PhDs in France in the last year or so, who did their theses _and_ defenses in English.

Comment: @penelope I can cite what my university calls _Charte des thèses_: "The thesis has to be written in French, except if there is a justified need due to the topic related to other language or culture. It is also possible that a part is written in another language if one is co-advised, or in English if requested by the PhD student." What I read there is, even if you want to write in English, you might not be given the possibility... Your case might be different, since you don't speak French, and it is clearly impossible to maintain your research while learning the language.

Comment: @PatW: in France, the obligation of writting the thesis in French is only half true: you can publish a sandwich thesis made of a detailed introduction in French and copies (or variants) of your published article in English.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Good to know, I will see what my advisor have to say about that.

Answer (score 10):

1. I don't usually read articles in my mother tongue. But I do regularly read articles in a language that is neither English nor my mother tongue (French, to be precise).
2. With regards to my mother tongue, the few exceptions are resources (articles, books) I received from some of my collaborators. I refer back to them purely for convenience. For French:

- there is (at least until very recently) still active research in my area performed by researchers who publish heavily in French; to gain access to those results sometimes it is necessary to read the original articles.
- there is a large corpus of useful literature from even the mid twentieth century that still hasn't been completely distilled into English language textbooks. (For mathematics, this refers mostly to *particular arguments* used in proofs. Quite often the same *result* would be available in English, but using a different method of attack. But there are also cases such as [from outside my field] [The EGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique).)
- translations may contain "errors". Sometimes it is good to go back to the original source.

3. I just cite them as I would any other source. Most style guides have sections on special rules for non-English and/or non-Latin-alphabet sources. Just follow them.

Answer (score 7):

Your three-part question is quickly answered:

1. Yes I read articles in my native language
2. Almost never because very few exist except older ones (ca. 1960s and older) and possibly bachelor or masters theses.
3. I would definitely cite them if they contained anything useful

Your concern is valid, regardless of preferences, using a common language ensures better spreading of the science. This does not mean non-English science is in any way uninteresting but will obviosuly be harder to find and read. It will be up to scientists in that language to bring the research to general attention. A possibility with thesis work is always to publish it or parts of it in journals and then translated. In such cases nothing is lost (except time for the complete re-writing)

EDIT: This answer was written for the original question which subsequently has been changed, also in terms of focus.

Comment: Publishing is not my biggest concern for the moment as it will become a little later. What amazes me is that you affirm reading articles in your native language, but it actually almost never happens. Are you looking for some specific publications/information or are you simply curious about what is done in your country?

Answer (score 5):

As a native English speaker who's working abroad, I am finally at the point where I can directly read the scientific literature in the local languages. However, in the past, I haven't hesitated to cite references in French (my "original" second language) when it was appropriate to do so. There are no challenges to do so, really, except making sure that you have the correct abbreviation for the journal title.

However, I would agree with the other posters that indicate that, today, scientific work needs to be in English if it is to reach the widest possible audience. Between the fact that a thesis gets nowhere near the number of "hits" as the papers that are derived from it, plus the fact that it's in a foreign language, and I would expect you to get very little in the way of citations for your thesis.

Comment: Maybe my question is misleading, but what interests me is why would you now read articles in "the local language"? What do you earn from them that you won't find in an English-written paper (except for the ideas)?

Comment: Well, usually it's because a work I'm reading (in English) cites the particular work, and therefore there's a reason to read it (because it's a data or method source).

Answer (score 5):

- I do read scientific literature in my mother tongue (German).
  For papers, that are mostly classics and not so recent. However, it is quite common in my field to write theses in German. And there are still serious and good scientific books as well as text books written in German, which I enjoy reading and citing as well.
- I'm also writing my thesis in German.

  - Main reason: My old university required that (would need to ask special permission for any other language). I changed university, but I'm not going to change the language as well.
  - The findings are/will be published also in English. So not having the thesis in English doesn't matter that much in terms of availability in English.
  - Second main reason: the thesis is the place where things are formulated in a less condensed manner than the papers. Such theses are good for teaching students who are usually not yet that fluent in English (applies to some kinds of foreign students as well!) nor in the subject.
- The same (more detailed, elaborate, less "it follows trivially" jumps of thought) is often true also for technical reports, which I read for exactly this reason (any kind of language I understand).
- I  cite literature I read in any language I understood (which not that much more than German and English, as I'm not as fluent in other languages).
- For the books, there is sometimes an English as well as a German version. But of course I cite the version that I acutally read.
  (If I'd be concerned that the English-only reader would not get from "Leary & Skoog: Instrumentelle Analytik" to "Leary & Skoog: Instrumental Analysis", I may put a note that points to the English version)
- Finally, how would you read and cite e.g. DIN 38402 A 51 if not in German?

Answer (score 3):

Although this may not answer your question, I just wanted to say that I did my PhD in France and did not write my thesis in french. I just wrote a summary (about 3 pages) in french, the rest was a compilation of articles. Since a serious publication can only be written in english nowadays, translating it in french would be a waste of time.

You should discuss with your advisor and see any way to get your thesis published in english. I do not think any legal argument holds.

Comment: Since a serious publication can only be written in english nowadays - I disagree. Language has nothing to do with the "serious"-ness or what I think you mean (acceptance, authenticity etc). Language only affects reach and spread. The quality of a publication has nothing to do with its language.

Comment: @Shion: Any publication in a non-English language nowadays is suspect. If it was any good, why didn't the authors submit it to a respected English-language journal? That they chose not to and instead publish in a regional journal is a signal that even they thought it was not very good. So, empirically, serious publications are almost exclusively in English (and most of the remainder is non-English only for legal reasons).

Comment: _Any publication in a non-English language nowadays is suspect._ — [citation needed] Hard to publish, sure, but _suspect_? Really?

Comment: I was on the committee for a French PhD student whose thesis had the abstract and introduction/overview in French and everything else in English. I suspect this law is enforced with variable precision in different French institutions/departments.  Check with your advisor. (Most French PhD students I've known simply produced two versions of their thesis; an official version in French, and a public version in English.)

Comment: @luispedro I will beg to differ with your assertion and will agree with JeffE. If you can provide a relevant citation [even if it is in another language] please do so. A publication in a non-English journal does not equate to a "non serious" publication. Deviating from the norm is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I don't have a citation, but if I find a recent paper written in a non-English language in a non-English language journal, my prior is that it is not very good. I don't know of a single non-English journal that I would consider to be on par with the average of the area. So, back to you: show me a single example of a non-English scientific journal that's considered important in its field.

Comment: @luispedro: I guess it depends on what you are looking for. If I need to read up or cite the relevant norms which I should/did follow, DIN or DIN-EN is my choice as I'm in Germany. If I need to read up or point to a concise summary of the current medical state-of-the-art I'd have a look for Leitlinien. If you want a journal, what about the Deutsche Ärzteblatt (note that it has a quite different *purpose* than Nature Medicine, and it is English-or-German language). And there are fields (though some may argue that they are not scientific) where you won't be able to avoid e.g. the Bundesanzeiger.

Comment: @cbeleites Fair enough. I think we were mostly talking about different sorts of publications as I would probably not really consider any of those a scientific publication, at least not primary publications, but secondary literature.

Comment: @luispedro: I think I know what you mean, you're restricting the scope to "original research papers", right? I guess if I'd look for good original research published in non-English languages, law, literature, language (l. didactics), (maybe even linguistics) would be fields where I'd start looking. As these are not my fields, this is just a heuristic. In any case, I'd have said that if you need to cite the Bundesanzeiger, it is as primary a source as it can possibly get. But it is a data source, you won't find original research papers there. (But I think possible continuations -> chat)